# Pass user identity from UI to data layer

Tags: c#

In order to perform auditing on a SQL 2008 database for updates / insert / delete, I was accessing

```
HttpContext.Current.User
```

in the datalayer to pass to a stored proc which would set the CONTEXT_INFO for auditing triggers.

These is probably wrong because if I wanted to put another UI (i.e. WinForms) the HttpContext wouldn't apply, however I don't want to add a username parameter to my BLL methods or add a constructor as all these methods are static.  What is the best way to access a user identity in the DAL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the static [Thread.CurrentPrincipal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.currentprincipal.aspx) property. Notice however that this property might not be equal to `HttpContext.Current.User` depending on your web application's impersonation settings.

A good solution might be to first check whether `HttpContext.Current` is not null. If it isn't then read the user from there, and otherwise fallback to reading `Thread.CurrentPrincipal`.

Comment: Thanks, is this available to WCF too?

Comment: Yes. Thread.CurrentPrincipal can actually be set by any part of the application/framework (if the necessary permission is granted). WCF should set it accordingly, but it may be overridden. For WCF, you may also want to have a look at [ServiceSecurityContext.PrimaryIdentity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.servicesecuritycontext.primaryidentity.aspx).

Comment: I disagree with even having the depending on System.Web.Mvc dll in your DAL layer, therefore you only have the option of Thread.CurrentPrincipal. However, what is the best way to impersonate the user from the UI to the DAL if the application pool identity is set?